# How did masculine Latin modus turn into feminine French mode?

Tags: étymologie, genre

I'm looking for some details on the development of feminine French *mode* from masculine Latin *modus*. Why was there a change in gender here? Both masculine *mode* and feminine *mode* mean more or less "manner", so what's the point of assigning femininity to *mode*? Is it possible that the feminine gender was by analogy with *manière* or *façon*?

Comment: According to [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mode) in the "Prononciation et étymologie" section, even the most ancient forms of what are now the masculine uses of the noun were initially feminine *(l'imperative mode, 1550 — en musique: trois modes: la phrygiene, et la doriene, et la lydiene, 1547)*, and postdate what became the modern feminine usage of it *(à la mode normande, ca.1393).* Looks like there would be more to dig to find the final answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

*Le mode* and *la mode* indeed share the same root but they are specialized so you cannot use one for another.

Despite *modus* being masculine in Latin, the gender of *mode* was initially essentially feminine for an unknown reason<sup>1</sup>. In parallel, there was also the masculine *[meuf/mœuf](https://www.littre.org/definition/moeuf)* also coming from the Latin *modus* which was used in grammar and music (mood).

Later, the masculine *mode* was reintroduced to agree with the Latin and distinguish "technical" use (masculine) from "non technical" (feminine). This masculine *mode* superseded the old masculine *meuf*, not to confuse with the new *verlan meuf* ;-)

<sup>1</sup><sub>While very rare, word gender change during the evolution from Latin to French did happen. For example the feminine *la fin* comes from the masculine Latin *finis*. Italian *il fine* and Spanish *el fin* kept the Latin gender. *La fleur* fem. comes from Latin *flos/floris*. Italian has *il fiore* masc. but Spanish has *la flor* fem.</sub>